# How to get the floor level

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary

I’m on a project having to draw the path on different floors on the indoor part of Google maps android api v2. I've enabled indoor, but is there any way I can attach a  listener or in any other way be notified of which floor level that is shown, or just get the name or number shown?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
        map.setOnIndoorStateChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onIndoorBuildingFocused() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIndoorLevelActivated(IndoorBuilding building) {
            int activeLevelIndex = building.getActiveLevelIndex();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In indoor path navigation the wifi based navigation is much better than the GPS. So one way to get the floor level you need to set an access point (AP) at the entering position of each floor, that is at the opening of elevator or stairs. So based on the signals from the AP you can distinguish the floor.

```
WifiManager wManager;
List<ScanResult> wifiList; 

wManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
// Inside BroadcastReceiver()
wifiList = wManager.getScanResults();
for (int i=0; i<wifiList.size(); i++){
    ScanResult scanresult = wManager.getScanResults().get(i);                        
    System.out.println("SSID: "+ssid);
    System.out.println("RSSI: "+scanresult.level);
   }
```

The SSID gives the name of AP and RSSI gives the signal strength. So with these data you can identify the floor, even if there exist another AP signal from nearer floor.

Comment: This would be useful if the problem was to know where the device was located, however, the issue is that I have to know which floor is shown on the map, and hereby draw the required path, even though I’m not physically located in the area.